# WebStorm image src absolute path - CANNOT display

Tags: css, html, image, webstorm, src

I'm new to HTML5. Just learned it for two weeks only, using WebStorm on Macbook air.

I have image source issues.

My question is:
Why image from absolute path can't be displayed?
[image: The path and error]

I'm sure the path is correct. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

B.R.
Laura

**EDIT: Thanks to all. Solved.

Comment: Try `/Users/Laura/Desktop/yamazakikento.jpg`, but nobody does it like that because your page would only work on your mac.

Comment: Hey Laura. For learning and testing purposes, there are a lot of free image hosting solutions out there for your photos.You could also use an image placeholder service (like Lorempixel) for a temporary demo solution.

Comment: Note that in HTML, almost all image (and other asset) paths are URLs: whether a full URL (like `http://localhost/site/images/image.jpg`) or relative URL (like `images/myimage.jpg`)

Comment: Thanks to all. Your answers help me a lot. I am learning how to display a image using an absolute path. i know it's never/hardly ever used in the web development. but as a beginner, i should know what it is. zstate's solution does work good. Thanks you @zstate and all others.

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm doesn't follow/resolve such links - only those files that belong to your project can be referenced. And such link won't work anyway when opening the page on built-in webserver - only files located in the project directory are served for security reasons